# how download file without robots?

Tags: java, selenium, download, webdriver, testng

I am creating an automatic test for some webs and I'm using WebDriver, TestNG and code that is written in Java. Now I have a small problem with downloading file. I need to download file from this link:

```
http://www.labmultis.info/jpecka.portal-exdrazby/files/catalog_documents/index.php?id=43756
```

This piece code below is not working and i dont want use robots, because it is not so good solution.

```
        FirefoxProfile prof = new FirefoxProfile();
        prof.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Users\\...");
        prof.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        prof.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
```

and i can't use checkbox do this automatically for files like this from now on.

```
http://s4.postimg.org/cnrxal2ql/download.png
```

Can anyone advise me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this settings:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", yourDownloadDir);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.downloadDir", yourDownloadDir);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", yourDownloadDir);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
    "text/plain,text/csv,application/comma-separated-values," +
    "application/vnd.ms-excel,application/pdf,application/msword,image/svg+xml,*/*");
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
```